# RPi3/B DC characteristics

Tags: gpio, hardware

I'm looking on page 13 of [this datasheet](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/computemodule/RPI-CM-DATASHEET-V1_0.pdf) for the Raspberry Pi's compute modules (CM1, CM3, and CM3L), and in Table 5 "DC Characteristics" under the "Conditions" column there is an undefined condition labeled "VDD_IO". Can someone who knows provide a definition for this condition? Is this perhaps the GPIOX-Y_VDD power supply voltage (see section 9.1 "GPIO" on page 17?